# Can't get data to display in textbox from a programmatically created datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am programmatically creating 3 datagridviews depending on what is selected in a listbox.

I am creating them this way because working with a lot of objects on the form is messy and difficult, this is a lot cleaner.

But no matter what type of event I introduce outside of the listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event, and I have looked at lots of websites and tried a half dozen different ways,  I can't get the text box I have created to display text from these datagridviews. (I have been working only with data from gridC so far)

I can't help but feel that the way the grid is being created has something to do with this. Has anyone done this before? I would really prefer to stick with creating them on the fly if possible.

Sorry if I have left out something someone might need to know.  Thank you!!

Code:
 (I've deleted the contents of the other two if statements):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;


namespace MyWiki_8_4_16
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<Connection String>");
        string qryQuery = null;
        DataGridView gridC = new DataGridView();
        DataGridView gridG = new DataGridView();
        DataGridView gridF = new DataGridView();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "select Stuff(table_name, 1, 4, '') as table_name  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables where table_name not like 'Ref%'", conn);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            this.listBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name";
            conn.Close();
            gridC.Visible = false;
            gridC.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
            string constring = ("Data Source=DSPL7722\\KATMO;Initial Catalog=Physics;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            if (text == "Categories")
            {
                con.Open();
                qryQuery = ("select Category from tbl_categories");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qryQuery, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                this.Controls.Add(gridC);
                gridC.DataSource = dt;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
                gridC.Visible = true;
                gridF.Visible = false;
                gridG.Visible = false;
                gridC.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            }
            else if (text == "Glossary")
            {

            }
            else if (text == "Formulas")
            {

            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.gridC.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                if (row != null)
                    txt_Col1.Text = row.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }//class
}//namespace
```

Another one:

```cs
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell cell = null;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in gridC.SelectedCells)
    {
        cell = selectedCell;
        break;
    }
    if (cell != null)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;
        txt_Col1.Text = row.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: "this is a lot cleaner". Don't tell your psychiatrist that. They'll keep you in the locked ward forever. Continuing on that general theme, your question is about displaying something in a textbox, but there is no textbox in your code. All this context is great, but ideally you should also include the part that's not working right.

Comment: There were so MANY snippets of code that didn't work that I took them all out!!!

Comment: //private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        //{

        //    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
        //    {
        //        DataGridViewRow row = this.gridC.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        //        if (row != null)
        //            txt_Col1.Text = row.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
        //    }
        //}

Comment: //private void gridC_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    DataGridViewRow dr = gridC.SelectedRows[0];
        //    txt_Col1.Text = dr.Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
        //   
        //}

Comment: Whoa, whoa -- nobody can read that. You can edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I can't find the others, in the beginning I tried a couple of different I tried a datagridview events, I'll try and recreate. Oops!  OK!

Comment: Where's the text box?

Comment: The text box is on the form, I have no code behind for it.

Comment: Do you have any code that interacts with it?

Comment: Only the code I am using to try and populate it. I added one snippet to the rest of the code.

Comment: The "text box" isn't really a text box, is it?

Comment: Hi Ed, I appreciate your willingness to help, but I've had to stop working on this :(

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the datatable to girdview datasource first and then filling it which is not correct and should be other way round like

```
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            this.Controls.Add(gridC);
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            gridC.DataSource = dt;
```

Moreover, looks like at any time you are using only one gridview based on the condition in `if` block and with that I see it's unnecessary to have 3 gridviews and as well there is no reason why you can't have it declared in design time.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you mean?

you want to pass the text/string value from your datagrid going to your textbox.

try this one

```
int index = gridC.CurrentRow.Index;
txt_Col1.Text = gridC.Rows[index].Cells["Category"].Value.ToString();
```